# How to Perform E2E login process and test more pages

Tags: reactjs, testing, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using `testcafe` in an `Electron-React` app trying to integrate some basic `e2e tests`.

The test works, however it's not relevant.

I would like to know i can **pass the login page and have extra clicks on the other pages.**

**App.e2e.js**

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import { getPageTitle, getPageUrl, fixture, test, login } from './helpers';

const assertNoConsoleErrors = async browser => {
  const { error } = await browser.getBrowserConsoleMessages();
  await browser.expect(error).eql([]);
};

fixture`Electron Client`.page('../../app/app.html').afterEach(assertNoConsoleErrors);

test('should atempt login without credentials', async browser => {
  await login({
    email: 'name@name.com',
    password: '123456',
    browser,
  });
  await browser
    .click('button[type=submit]')
    .expect(getPageUrl())
    .contains('/login');

  const email = Selector('[name="email"]');
  const password = Selector('[name="password"]');

  await browser.expect(email.value).eql('name@name.com');
  await browser.expect(password.value).eql('123456');
});
```

**helpers.js**

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

export const getPageTitle = ClientFunction(() => document.title);

export const fixture = (...args) => global.fixture(...args);

export const test = (...args) => global.test(...args);

export const getPageUrl = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href);

export const login = async ({ email, password, browser }) => {
  await browser.typeText('[data-test="email"]', email);
  await browser.typeText('[data-test="password"]', password);
  await browser.click('button[type=submit]');
};
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "pass the login page and have extra clicks on the other pages"? Would user roles work for what you're looking for?: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html

Comment: I have seen the user Roles, but i don't see how i can use them. As i mentioned, my app is using Electron-React.
The examples i see are using `Role('http://example.com/login'` that does not work in my case because my app is a SPA that uses only one app.html and the rest is React and JS files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [User Roles API](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) to meet your requirements.
See an example below.

```js
const loginAsTestUser = Role('../../app/app.html', async t => {
   await t
      .typeText('[data-test="email"]', email)
      .typeText('[data-test="password"]', password)
      .click('button[type=submit]');
});

fixture`Electron Client`
    .page('../../app/app.html')
    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.useRole(loginAsTestUser);
    });
    .afterEach(assertNoConsoleErrors);

test('should atempt login without credentials', async browser => {

  await browser
    .click('button[type=submit]')
    .expect(getPageUrl())
    .contains('/login');

  const email = Selector('[name="email"]');
  const password = Selector('[name="password"]');

  await browser.expect(email.value).eql('name@name.com');
  await browser.expect(password.value).eql('123456');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! 
I tried using it and i'm getting an error ` [ 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined' ] }` when i add the `Role('../../app/app.html',...` I think it's a path issue related to this being an Electron-React app.

Comment: Please provide an Electron app example with a test in which we can reproduce the issue.